# Do C# properties always have backup fields "behind the scene"?

Tags: c#, properties, cil

I know that when we use properties in C#, the compiler always generate getters and setters for them in CIL (i.e., get_PropertyName and set_PropertyName), for example, consider the following piece of code:

```
    class Program
    {
        class Test
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Here I'm using reflection to inspect methods of Test class
            Type type = typeof(Test);
            foreach (var item in type.GetMethods())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

This program will produce output with the methods of `Test`, among which there will be `get_Name` and `set_Name` - the getter and setters I was talking about.
From my understanding then, if getters and setter are created "behind the scenes" then there should be a backing field created as well from which/to which the getters and setter get/set values.
So, from the previous example, I can use reflection to inspect fields for Test class, like that:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type = typeof(Test);
        foreach (var item in type.GetFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
    }
```

The ouput of this program is empty, I assume this is because the backing field that was created has `private` access, so we cannot see it. But since I don't know how to check it, can you please let me know if a backing field always gets created (even if we have a simple property with only `get;` and `set;`) ?

Comment: As far as i know they do.

Comment: Just so you can find other reference material more easily: these are usually known as *backing* fields, not *backup* fields.

Comment: Funny that a feature added in later versions of C# has overshadowed their primary use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean simple properties like:

```
{get;set;}
```

or:

```
{get;}
```

then yes, there is a field; add `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` to your `GetFields()` call and you'll see it:

```
foreach (var item in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

It usually has an unpronouncable name involving `<>` - yours is `<Name>k__BackingField` on my machine - but: this name is a compiler feature (although a lot of serialization etc libraries make use of it, so it is unlikely to change).

But: no, properties don't *by themselves* always involve fields; for example:

```
public int Value => 42; // no field
```

or

```
public int Name { get { return obj.Name; } set { obj.Name = value; } }
```

Answer (score 13):

> But since I don't know how to check it, can you please let me know if a backup field always get created (even if we have a simple property with only get; and set; ?

An *automatically implemented* property, e.g.

```
public int ReadWriteProperty { get; set; }
public int ReadOnlyProperty { get; }
```

will indeed always have a backing field generated by the compiler. But if you provide your own implementation of the getter/setter, then the compiler won't generate a field:

```
public int Zero => 0;

public int IgnoresSetter
{
    get { return 10; }
    set { /* Meh. Whatever you say, I'm still going to return 10 in the getter... */ }
}
```

Neither of those will cause a field to be generated.